# Multiple toastr js click function

Tags: javascript, php, html, toastr

I'm fetching multiple post from DB. There is a option for make post as Favourite, I'm using toastr for showing notification. every post has a  `id="favourite_ads"`. but toastr notification only works for the 1st post. But i want to show notification for all of the posts. I have uploaded snapshot.

Please help.

[image: snapshot]

[image: snapshot]

Comment: Id's have to be unique. You should use classes instead.

Comment: please can you give me a example code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the `id` attribute by common classes since the identifier should ne unique in the same document.

If you've duplicated identifiers always the first one will be considered that why the toastr works just for the first post.

```
<a class="btn btn-defaul.... favorite_ads" ><span>add as Favourite </span></a>

$('.favourite_ads').click(function(){
    ...
});
```

Use class instead then your code should be like the above example.

Comment: please can you give me a example code?

Comment: Check the update, or you could just use the class `make-favorite` and remove the `id` attribute at all.